Issue with Expandrive key when trying to update Ubuntu
I'm having issues updating Ubuntu. I received a prompt from the software updater to upgrade to version 24 from 22 but it fails with "Failed to download repository information. Check your internet connection." This led to me trying some terminal commands and just trying to update my system in general. I tried to run sudo apt-get update which returns:
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease                          
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease                                             
Get:4 https://packages.expandrive.com/expandrive stable InRelease [2,505 B]                                                           
Hit:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease                                 
Err:4 https://packages.expandrive.com/expandrive stable InRelease
  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 0FB0547682F8C86A ExpanDrive, Inc. <support@expandrive.com>
Hit:6 https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu noble-apps-security InRelease
Hit:7 https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu noble-apps-updates InRelease
Hit:8 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu noble-infra-security InRelease
Hit:9 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu noble-infra-updates InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: https://packages.expandrive.com/expandrive stable InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 0FB0547682F8C86A ExpanDrive, Inc. <support@expandrive.com>
E: The repository 'https://packages.expandrive.com/expandrive stable InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

I did not have Expandrive installed when first encountering this. I did a long time ago but never used it. I have tried reinstalling it, uninstalling with purge, removing the key and anything else for remotely similar problems I've found online. I found a similar problem on here which was linked to an older question (invalid signatures EXPKEYSIG) but I couldn't get it to work based on that either. I'm not very familiar with this stuff, so any help is appreciated. I do not want Expandrive on my system, so if the solution involves nuking that, then even better.
If you need more info, I'll gladly add it. Thanks.

Software & Updates -> Other Software tab and check to see if Expandrive is listed there. Initially, if checked, uncheck it to see if that makes a difference. If it does, highlight it and select Remove if you have no further use for it.
